# How to make an icon animation that changes as you drag and drop it

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I need to make an animation which would change the icon's state based on the shift in coordinates as a percentage, I did it but my interface became slow, if I remove the icons from it then everything is fine, I wrote it very badly but this is the only option I could do

```
@Composable
fun RecommendationIcon(
    bookCardController: BookCardController,
    modifier: Modifier,
    size: Dp,
    color: Color,
    icon: Int,
    alpha: Float,
    description: String
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Box {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                    contentDescription = description,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(size),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(bookCardController.baseIconColor)
                )
            }
            Box {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                    contentDescription = description,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(size + 20.dp)
                        .alpha(alpha / 3),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color)
                )
            }
            Box {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(
                        id = icon
                    ),
                    contentDescription = description,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(size)
                        .alpha(alpha),
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

bookCardController is responsible for changing the state, which changes when the card is moved.

all icon states are animatable
[image]
[image]
[image]